# HAProxy: replacing subdomains with paths

Tags: haproxy, subdomain, path, dsm

My previous question was too complicated and unclear. Hopefully this is more straight to the point...

Currently I'm using subdomains to access application UIs externally. Some allow access via paths:

```
example.com/sabnzbd
```

Others don't work with paths (get 404 errors) and require subdomains:

```
dsm.example.com
```

Basically - I'm trying to get access to various backends using only paths:

Instead of `plex.example.com` I'm after `example.com/plex`

Instead of `dsm.example.com` I'm after `example.com/dsm`

Sabnzbd works because it allows me to configure a URL base (set to /sabnzbd). As for the plex and dsm examples, I'm assuming that /plex and /dsm don't exist on their respective web servers hence serving me a 404.

So I'm trying to figure out how to strip the /plex and /dsm paths from the requests that go to the backend (but leaves them in the URL bar).

Is this possible?

Comment: Your examples are a little bit abstract, so it's hard to tell exactly what you're wanting to rewrite as what... but one thing is that ACLs do not work quite like you may expect.  If you rewrite a request with reqrep, `use_backend if some_acl` needs to reference an ACL that will match the request *after* reqrep has modified it -- not the request as it looked when it first arrived.  The truthiness of ACLs changes mid-stream when you use reqrep.

Comment: Sorry about that. I understand that it was very convoluted. Hopefully the re-written question makes more sense?

Comment: To clarify, do you want `example.com/plex` (browser URL) to serve `plex.example.com/` (backend)?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'm after! (except the backend will be something like 10.10.1.1:32400). Currently, I go to plex.example.com but want to change to example.com/plex